# OpenCV c++ Error trying to load depth file

Tags: c++, opencv

currently I am working on a program that uses a depth file.  However, when I attempt to load this file, I keep getting build errors.  I am not getting any error notifications, however, so I am not sure what the problem is.  The process of me trying to load the file can be seen below.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


#define WIDTH 640
#define HEIGHT 480
#define F 524
#define CX 316
#define CY 256




int main()
{
    
    Mat depth;
    depth.create(480, 640, CV_16UC1);
    FILE *fp = fopen("depth.dat", "rb");
    fread(depth.data, 2, WIDTH * HEIGHT, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    imshow("depth image", depth);
    int k = waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Always check that `fopen`and `fread` suceeds! If you don't get any error notifications, how can you be sure that you get build errors?

Comment: How should I go about doing this?

Comment: `fopen` returns a null-pointer if it fails. `fread`  should return `WIDTH * HEIGHT` in this program, otherwise, the file didn't contain that many elements. Also, don't `#include <stdio.h>` in C++, `#include <cstdio>`

Comment: So I should be checking for  a null pointer? How can I do this? And if it does return one, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: `if(fp == nullptr) { std::perror("image.dat"); } else { /* it succeeded, put the rest of your program here */ }`

Comment: I just ran it with this and it just ran without telling me anything.

Comment: Then you probably made a mistake.[This code works](https://godbolt.org/z/Weq3WGx7a)

Comment: @TedLyngmo If you look at the edits I made on the main question, this is what I get for both the image and the command window.  Not sure why the image is displaying just a black screen.

Comment: You should put the error output in the question _as text_ not as a picture. Anyway, the problem is that the `DLL`'s can't be loaded. Are the `DLL` files it tries to load placed where it tries to load them?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The .dat file is stored in the same location as regular images are in the program and they are loading correctly.

Comment: The three `DLL` files are _not_ loaded correctly - that is what the error output clearly says.

Comment: everyone's been missing the point. your imshow window **isn't** completely black. look closely. you pass CV_16U data to imshow... that's going to be difficult. convert the data to uint8 and a range of 0 to 255, **or (better)** convert to float32 and a range of 0.0 to 1.0. I've stretched the range of your screenshot in a photo editor: https://imgur.com/a/FnVWVKx